# How to manually embed an Instagram post in vue.js in 2021

Tags: vue.js, instagram

I want to insert the publicly available embed code, provided by Instagram for one post, into my vue.js app.
Instagram provides an embed snippet for any post in the 3 dots at the top right of any Instagram post.

If I paste this in my Vue template I get this error:

> "Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed."

What does this mean and how can I get round it in Vue?

I have looked at several npm packages for embedding Instagram posts in Vue, but they all appear to have stopped working with Instagram's new nightmare authentication process. If I paste this into a vanilla html page (without Vue) it works fine.

I am using Gridsome with Vuetify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<script` from embed code and import it in this way https://gridsome.org/docs/head/

Comment: The script that Instagram provides is 
    `<script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>`
In main.js I changed this to
    `src: 'https://www.instagram.com/embed.js'`
I didn't know what to do with async.

On local this brings in the Instagram post, but every time I revisit the page I have to refresh.

On Netlify the Instagram post arrives sometimes and my site menu does not work. I have to refresh each page. Please see https://sad-noyce-47b3ee.netlify.app

Comment: Just try with `async: true` like ```head.script.push({
    src: 'https://www.instagram.com/embed.js',
    async: true
  })```

Comment: Thank you. That's made the site a whole lot faster, but I still need to refresh the homepage after returning to it from one of my other pages - or the Instagram box stays empty. You can see the behaviour at https://sad-noyce-47b3ee.netlify.app/

Comment: @nigelwhite see my answer .. I had the same issue and triggering process() solved it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you figured this out already, but loading the script (as in the accepted answer) and executing this in the component solved this problem for me:
`if (window.instgrm) window.instgrm.Embeds.process()`